# Angular 4. Use service to share data from API response OR save inside component

Tags: angular, performance, optimization

I would like to know what is the best for the perfomance of an application when i use data binding in html e.g:

**service.ts**
`private title:string;` 
`this.http.get(....).map( response =>{
    *some logic here* 
    this.tile= response.title;
    return response;
});`

`public getTitle():string{
   return this.title;
}`

**home.component.ts** 
`public title:string;` 
`ngOnInit() { 
   this.title = this.service.getTitle();
 }`

1) Get data from API requests and create methods to get/set that data inside the service and instantly show them in html e.g. `{{ service.getTitle() }}` **OR** 
2) Get data from API requests, manipulate them once in service and then send and save them in component to use it. `{{ title }}`
I do this question because the default changeDetectionStrategy will have to reach the service each time a change is detected and this happens so many times.

Comment: As `getTitle()` method  return `undefined` till the title gotten from the server. So that's (first option) not the best case.

Comment: the html part of the application will not render until the API calls has finished. I always get the same result in both cases.

Comment: Okay, Instead of using local variable at `home.component.ts` , you can create and use local variable from `service` itself. 
If there is logic before fetching `title` then use `{{service.getTitle()}}`
else, use `title` property of service itself. i.e. `{{service.title}}`

Comment: So it's better for perfomance to fetch the data from the service even though the component  has to reach the service, instead of creating double variables ( service.title -> home.title ) to local component, right?

Comment: I wouldnt say it is better in performance. it would be almost same performance.  Its is just that the `{{service.title}}` will always be the latest value, IF `title` changes over time.